# Reset local scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am (trying) to use scopes to handle some "filtering" within my models.

I got two scopes on the model: `verified` and `unverified`. Unfortunately the `verification` is not a single field in the database, but a query like:

```
return $query->whereHas('profile', function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('invitations', function ($i) {
                ...
        });
```

Now I got the following issue: If I scope like this

```php
$verified_members = $members->verified();
```

and work with `$verified_members` everything works fine:

```php
$verified_members->whereHas('car', function ($q) {
            $q->where('stolen', true);
        })->count();
```

but if I do something like:

```php
$verified_members = $members->verified();
$unverified_members = $members->unverified();

$verified_members->whereHas('car', function ($q) {
    $q->where('stolen', true);
})->count();

$unverified_members->whereHas('car', function ($q) {
    $q->where('stolen', true);
})->count();
```

I get `0` as result for `$unverified_members`, as it seems like the scopes are being chained. If I remove `$verified_members` again, I am getting results for `$unverified_members`.

Comment: Yes, `$members` is a collection of eloquent models which is mutated by the calls of verified() and unverified(). 
Something like this should work assuming you have a `Member` model where the scopes are defined :
`$verified_members = Member::verified();`
`$unverified_members = Member::unverified();`
If this works I can post an more structured answer :)